# Matlab: concat row vectors into an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

how can I add, for example vector

```
v1 = [0 0 0 1]
v2 = [0 1 0 0]
```

so that I get an array

```
a = 0 0 0 1
    0 1 0 0
```

and also add more vectors to, into array `a`?

Answer (score 2):

if you have 2 row vectors v1 = [0 0 0 1], and v2 = [0 1 0 0]

v3 = [v1, v2]
yields

`v3 = [ 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 ]`

v3 = [v1; v2]
yields

`v3 = 
[ 0 0 0 1  

       0 1 0 0 ]`

Answer (score 2):

A part from the prior answers I suggest that you check the following functions: horzcat, vertcat and reshape.

For instance test this code:

```
A1 = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
A2 = A1 + 10*ones(3,3); 
B1 = horzcat(A1,A2)         % horizontal concatenation
B1 = vertcat(A1,A2)         % vertical concatenation
v1 = reshape(A, 1, prod(size(A)))   % easily change the size of matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate them by using the following syntax:

```
a = [v1 v2]
```

Hope this works

Comment: your matrix `a` will NOT be a matrix just a long vector. See [Yuri](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5200298/1714410)'s answer for the correct way