# Combine linspace vectors for non uniform partition

Tags: matlab

I want to make a non uniform partition, in the sense that after a certain value `a` the difference between two x-values is lower or higher than the one before `a`.

So I want to make a vector that is the union of two different `linspace` vectors, with different number of points. For example:

```
% Inputs: a, L (which is greater than a), N1 and N2
x = linspace(0, a, N1); 
y = linspace(a, L, N2);
```

After this I would like to have a `z` vector which has all the points from `x` and `y`, and as a consequence having

```
% Interval over point a not equal
z(a)-z(a-1)~=z(a+1)-z(a) 
% Interval after point a equal
z(a+4)-z(a+3)=z(a+3)-z(a+2)
```

Such as:

```
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 10 12 14 16 ]
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `z = [x y]`?

Comment: wait, my bad i was using z=[ x;y] instead of that... shame on me , thanks

Comment: In future, try and really simplify your question before asking it. Framing this as "non uniform partitions" made it almost unanswerable. Framing this as "Concatenate / combine two row vectors" would have taken you [to the docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) or [to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200209/matlab-concat-row-vectors-into-an-array) straight from Google. Happy I could help.